# How can I delete a row from the database?

Tags: 8, database

I would like to delete all rows from the database that is older than 1 month. How can I do that in Drupal 8?

> DELETE FROM myTable WHERE MyColumn < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it by using this code

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->delete('table');
$query->condition('some column', 'some condition');
$query->execute();
```